# How to clip/mask a sprite

Tags: godot, godot4

I know it's possible to clip children nodes. But in this case the clipped content is relative to the mask's transform. Which means if I position/rotate/scale the mask, the contents do the same and the image is pretty much static.

In my case I want the mask to rotate, but the contents to stay upright relatively to the global space.

[image]

I tried to use 'Top level' for the star, but then clipping doesn't work. Maybe I used it wrong, IDK.

The only workaround I can think of is to programmatically fix the star's local rotation so its global one will stay 0. But it's kind of a hassle and I hope there's a better approach. With 1 object it may be not such a big deal, but if there's a complex scene behind a mask with many objects, it will gain complexity very soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a light.

First add a `Light2D`, give it as `texture` your mask.

And then give the `CanvasItem` (`Node2D` or `Control`) that you want to hide/reveal a `CanvasItemMaterial`, and set its `light_mode` property to "Light Only".

Finally, move your `Light2D` to reveal different parts of the `CanvasItem`.

**Note**: You can use the `light_mask` of the `Light2D` control which objects are illuminated by it, and `light_mask` of the `CanvasItem` to control which lights illuminate them.